# THREE.js - Plot a Simple x,y coordinate on a canvas

Tags: javascript, three.js, html5-canvas, data-visualization

I have a simple HTML5 page with the latest version of THREE.js installed. My goal is to plot 10 simple x, y coordinates on a canvas. See code below. I'm hoping for the following. I am making the following assumptions, as I can't find anything to the contrary:-

- THREE.js will plot from the top left corner of the canvas, in the number of pixels specified in `THREE.Vector2()` so `THREE.Vector2(100,100)` will plot 100px right and 100px down from the top left.
- Points will be 1px wide by 1px high.
- All points will be white.

I receive a black canvas, and I'm stumped. No console errors and no feedback on what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone advise?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js" type="text/javascript">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

//This will add a starfield to the background of a scene
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var star = new THREE.Vector2(100*i,100*i);
    geometry.vertices.push(star);
}

var material = new THREE.PointsMaterial({ color: 0xFFFFFF });

var data = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);

scene.add(data);

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
animate();
</script>
</body>`
```

Bonus point, is there a way to specify the size of the point drawn?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You first assumption is wrong, a vector set at `(100, 100)` in 3D space does not mean a point 100px from the top and left in 2D space. If you want to plot a simple 2D grid using strict `x, y` pixel positions on a canvas, I recommend you use the 2D canvas context instead of using Three.js. 3D engines use unitless values that don't follow pixel dimensions in the same way as HTML/CSS does. Their positions can vary wildly based on camera projection, window aspect ratios, zoom, field of view, etc.